# get only root levels of taxonomy in view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

I have Hierarchical vocabulary like

---

Audi

- A3

BMW

- BMW c4
- BMW x11

---

In my views page I want to all parent terms in page, like

---

Audi

BMW

---

How to do this?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can get that with the URL like

```
taxonomy/term/[tid]/all
```

This will display the content of all subterms.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to vary by site.

If you install the pathauto module (http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) you can do this easily.

Once pathauto is installed, hop over to /admin/build/path/pathauto and expand 'Taxonomy term paths.'

What you want to do might not be the same as me, but I like to use:

```
category/[vocab-raw]/[catpath-raw]
```

This gets me all the data I need at:

```
example.com/category/tags/[term]
```

If you don't want that, consider going with views which allows for lots of customization, including the URL.